# QFileDialog.getOpenFileName truncation on linux

Tags: qt, pyside, qfiledialog, getopenfilename

For a file located `/home/rrg29876/villy/air.out`, all is well when I run the following code in Windows:

```py
#Open a FileDialog to pull in supported data
formats = ("R Output Files (*.out);;"
           "Rc Output Files (*.out);;"
           "A Average Files (*.avg);;"
           "A Timestep Files (*.tim)")
fileName, filtr = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
    "Select A Data File to Open", self.defdir, formats)
self.defdir = path.split(fileName)[0]

print "self.defdir: ",self.defdir
print "fileName: ", fileName
print "filtr: ", filtr
```

But in Linux I get:

```
self.defdir: /home/rrg29876/vill
fileName:  home/rrg29876/villy/D
filtr:  Rc Output
```

and then I cannot do anything in my program because the filename and filtr are wrong..

Can anyone help explain this truncation to me and/or suggest ways to fix/get around this?

Comment: What are your versions of python, pyside and Qt?

Comment: We are using python 2.7, pyside 1.2.2, and PyQt4.

Comment: Looks like a borked PySide installation. Did you compile it yourself on Linux?

Comment: No, it was installed on our cluster by technical staff.

Comment: It works well for me with the same versions.

Comment: @RyanGrove. I've seen similar issues with corrupted strings which were due to the pyside libs failing to pick up the right python libs at runtime. Do you see anything different if you do: `print repr(self.defdir)`?

Comment: I forgot to say: I also cannot reproduce the problem on Linux (PySide-1.2.2 and Qt-4.8.7).

Comment: Yes, hahaha.. I get the following: u'/\x00t\x00c\x00s\x00/\x00w\x00a\x00o\x00/\x00h\x00o\x00m\x00e\x00/\x00r\x00r\x00g\x002\x009\x008\x007\x006\x00/\x00v\x00i\x00c\x00e\x00'

Comment: @RyanGrove. Not sure I understand your "hahaha". A unicode string would never normally contain all those null characters. And a unix filepath categorically *cannot ever* include them. So it does look very much like your pyside installation is borked, as I suggested earlier.

Comment: The "hahaha" translates roughly into "Ahhhh, I see the problem now".  I appreciate your help!